# Should I run a separate thread to save the model in Pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, pytorch

Consider the following snippet from [PyTorch Imagenet Example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/91f230a13b95c6259e5cb22b6cef355de998cede/word_language_model/main.py#L193-L210) (Please notice the "**#AREA OF INTEREST**"):

```
try:
for epoch in range(1, args.epochs+1):
    epoch_start_time = time.time()
    train()
    val_loss = evaluate(val_data)
    # Save the model if the validation loss is the best we've seen so far.
    if not best_val_loss or val_loss < best_val_loss:
        # AREA OF INTEREST ##########
        with open(args.save, 'wb') as f:
            torch.save(model, f)
        #############################
        best_val_loss = val_loss
    else:
        # Anneal the learning rate if no improvement has been seen in the validation dataset.
        lr /= 4.0
```

The question is: should I run a separate thread that saves the model *in order to save time*, or am I overkilling the process? i.e., it does not worth running a separate thread? I've checked the doc of [torch.save](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=save#torch.save) but I did not find what I want.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your model size. If you have slow IO and big model it may take time. But usual FS cache is big enough to store a whole model.